# Flatten nested lists in dataframe after JSON import in R

Tags: r, json

I have numerous JSON files each with many flight-data records. A record looks like the following JSON structure.

```json
[
    {
        "flight": {
            "operatingAirline": {
                "iataCode": "NH",
                "icaoCode": "ANA",
                "airlineDisplayCode": "NH",
                "name": "ANA All Nippon Airways"
            },
            "serviceTypeCode":"PP",
            "aircraftType": {
                "icaoCode": "B77W",
                "modelName": "B77W",
                "registration": "JA792A"
            },
            "flightNumber": {
                "airlineCode": "NH",
                "trackNumber": "00203",
                "suffix": ""
            },
            "codeShares": [
                {
                    "codeShare": {
                        "airlineCode": "LH",
                        "trackNumber": "04921",
                        "suffix": ""
                    }
                }
            ],
            "departureAirport": "HND",
            "arrivalAirport": "FRA",
            "originDate": "2016-02-23",
            "arrival": {
                "scheduled": "2016-02-23T04:20:00Z",
                "estimated": "2016-02-23T04:16:00Z",
                "actual": "2016-02-23T04:16:16Z",
                "terminal": "1",
                "gates": {
                    "gate": "B48A"
                },
                "baggageClaim": {
                    "carousel": "19"
                }
            },
            "flightStatus": ""
        }
    }
]
```

But executing the following gives me a not completely flat dataframe.

```r
library(jsonlite)

df <- fromJSON(paste(getwd(), "test-data/arrival-2020-01-28-00-36.json", sep='/'), flatten=TRUE)
```

For example the columns `flight.codeShares` and `flight.arrival.gates` contain lists, which prevents the dataframe from being stored in a sqlite file. I'm looking for a solution to process a JSON file with multiple records at once.

In the pyton ecosystem there is a `json_normalize` function, which does the job. How can i do this in R?

Comment: Just to make sure: what you want is a data frame that is completely flat i.e. does not contain any data nested into a cell but rather breaks the nested data structure into several columns?.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure there is a universal solution. The problem in your particular case is that
`flight.codeShares` is interpreted as data frame *inside* a list *inside* of the column.
If it was just a data frame inside a column, then `flatten()` would work.
Of course, you can get around this by flattening `codeShares` manually, adding it
to the data frame and removing the the original column.

```r
library(jsonlite)
json <- '[{
    "flight": {
      "operatingAirline": {
        "iataCode": "NH",
        "icaoCode": "ANA",
        "airlineDisplayCode": "NH",
        "name": "ANA All Nippon Airways"
      },
      "serviceTypeCode":"PP",
      "aircraftType": {
        "icaoCode": "B77W",
        "modelName": "B77W",
        "registration": "JA792A"
      },
      "flightNumber": {
        "airlineCode": "NH",
        "trackNumber": "00203",
        "suffix": ""
      },
      "codeShares": [
        {
          "codeShare": {
            "airlineCode": "LH",
            "trackNumber": "04921",
            "suffix": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "codeShare": {
            "airlineCode": "??",
            "trackNumber": "99999",
            "suffix": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "departureAirport": "HND",
      "arrivalAirport": "FRA",
      "originDate": "2016-02-23",
      "arrival": {
        "scheduled": "2016-02-23T04:20:00Z",
        "estimated": "2016-02-23T04:16:00Z",
        "actual": "2016-02-23T04:16:16Z",
        "terminal": "1",
        "gates": {
          "gate": "B48A"
        },
        "baggageClaim": {
          "carousel": "19"
        }
      },
      "flightStatus": ""
    }
}]'
df <- fromJSON(json, flatten=TRUE, simplifyVector = TRUE)
df <- cbind(df, flatten(df$flight.codeShares[[1]]))
#> Warning in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE): Zeilennamen wurden in einer
#> short Variablen gefunden und wurden verworfen
df$flight.codeShares <- NULL
```

Check the result

```r
names(df)
#>  [1] "flight.serviceTypeCode"                    
#>  [2] "flight.departureAirport"                   
#>  [3] "flight.arrivalAirport"                     
#>  [4] "flight.originDate"                         
#>  [5] "flight.flightStatus"                       
#>  [6] "flight.operatingAirline.iataCode"          
#>  [7] "flight.operatingAirline.icaoCode"          
#>  [8] "flight.operatingAirline.airlineDisplayCode"
#>  [9] "flight.operatingAirline.name"              
#> [10] "flight.aircraftType.icaoCode"              
#> [11] "flight.aircraftType.modelName"             
#> [12] "flight.aircraftType.registration"          
#> [13] "flight.flightNumber.airlineCode"           
#> [14] "flight.flightNumber.trackNumber"           
#> [15] "flight.flightNumber.suffix"                
#> [16] "flight.arrival.scheduled"                  
#> [17] "flight.arrival.estimated"                  
#> [18] "flight.arrival.actual"                     
#> [19] "flight.arrival.terminal"                   
#> [20] "flight.arrival.gates.gate"                 
#> [21] "flight.arrival.baggageClaim.carousel"      
#> [22] "codeShare.airlineCode"                     
#> [23] "codeShare.trackNumber"                     
#> [24] "codeShare.suffix"
dim(df)
#> [1]  2 24
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This seems to work for one record. What if i got multiple rows in the `flight.codeShares` column?

Comment: I tried it and changed the answer accordingly. I get a warning and a data frane with two rows. Most of the data has been replicated except for `codeshares`. In general it works but it may not be what you expect. If that is not what you need, please update your question and add more details,

Comment: Thanks, i updated my question accordingly. Maybe i was not clear enough, my bad.